# Laptop screen fuzzing only after I reset my computer

Tags: laptop, display

I'm not one to fully turn off my laptop that often. For the last few weeks, when my HP Pavilion dm4 (Windows 7) has been coming out of hibernation, the screen kind of fuzzes from black to white to gray during the time when the bar at the bottom would be saying "coming out of hibernation". However, it always clicks back to normal as soon as the regular blue login screen comes up and asks for my password. Today I reset my computer to install Windows updates, and now the fuzz remains even after Windows loads. I hooked up an extra external moniter for now to find out what the issue is and it works fine. I checked the drivers; they are up to date. I tried bending the screen back and forth with no observable change (though I might have thought there is a loose ribbon cable somewhere). I tried hibernating and waking up, but that didn't help.

Does this sound like a hardware issue? If so why did it only start once I reset the computer? Is this a software issue? What could be the issue and why would shutting off the computer affect that?

Answer (score 0):

when you run the laptop and the screen at the same time are the colours still the same on the laptop screen?

This sounds very much driver related, and if this had happened to me the first thing that i would try would be a system restore to a point before the any recent updates.  i would then update the graphics cards via the site and auto scan if possible.  something somewhere has caused the driver to error out.  The really is if it works with an external screen fine or not.  you could also try windows key and 'p' to see if its been set to external output only.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment (you have enough rep to do so). Maybe make it a bit more concise so it will fit, or multiple comments.